# Swift extension of a class ONLY when it conforms to a specific protocol

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift-protocols, swift-extensions

Hi there =) I was just faced with a design problem where I need to (essentially) do the following:

I want to inject a bit of code on `viewWillAppear:` of **any `UIViewController` subclass that conforms to a protocol `MyProtocol`**. Explained in code:

```
protocol MyProtocol
{
    func protocolFunction() {
        //do cool stuff...
    }
}

extension UIViewController where Self: MyProtocol //<-----compilation error
{
    public override class func initialize()
    {
        //swizzling stuff switching viewWillAppear(_: Bool) with xxx_viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    }

    //  MARK: - Swizzling

    func xxx_viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        self.xxx_viewWillAppear(animated)

        //invoke APIs from  
        self.protocolFunction() // MyProtocol APIs
        let viewLoaded = self.isViewLoaded // UIViewController APIs

    }
}
```

The main issue here is that I need to 2 two things in the `UIVIewController` extension:

1. Invoke both `MyProtocol` and `UIViewController` API's
2. Override `UIViewController` method `initialize()` in order to be able to swizzle `viewWillAppear:`

These 2 capabilities seem incompatible (as of Swift 3) because:

1. We **can't extend classes with conditions** (i.e `extension UIViewController where Self: MyProtocol`)
2. if we instead **extend the protocol**, we CAN add conditions `extension MyProtocol where Self: UIViewController` but **we CAN'T override methods from a class in a protocol extension**, meaning we can't `public override class func initialize()` which is needed for swizzling.

So I was wondering if there's somebody out there who can offer a Swifty solution to this problem I'm facing?  =)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why not to use simple inheritance? It's ideal for overriding default class methods.

Comment: Hey @MaxPevsner thanks for the comment! =) I choose not to use inheritance because I'm building this as part of a system to be used in multiple projects and I don't want the API to force each project's UIViewControllers to inherit from a specific superclass ('cause maybe each of those projects require their own base class) so if possible i'd like to avoid that.

Comment: I believe, you're missing a point here. But that discussion is far beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, thus far I've found no truly satisfactory way of doing it, but I decided to post what I ended up doing for this particular problem.
In a nutshell, the solution goes like this (using the original example code):

```
protocol MyProtocol
{
    func protocolFunction() {
        //do cool stuff...
    }
}

extension UIViewController //------->simple extension on UIViewController directly
{
    public override class func initialize()
    {
        //swizzling stuff switching viewWillAppear(_: Bool) with xxx_viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    }

    //  MARK: - Swizzling

    func xxx_viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        self.xxx_viewWillAppear(animated)

        //------->only run when self conforms to MyProtocol
        if let protocolConformingSelf = self as? MyProtocol { 
            //invoke APIs from  
            protocolConformingSelf.protocolFunction() // MyProtocol APIs
            let viewLoaded = protocolConformingSelf.isViewLoaded // UIViewController APIs
        }

    }

}
```

Drawbacks:

- Not "the Swift way" of doing things
- The swizzling method will be invoked and take effect on ALL `UIViewControllers`, even though we validate for only those that conform to the `MyProtocol` protocol to run the sensitive lines of code.

I very much hope it helps anyone else out there facing a similar situation =)

Answer (score 16):

You were near the solution. Just need to make it other way around. Extend protocol only if its part of UIViewController.

```
protocol MyProtocol
{
  func protocolFunction() {
    //do cool stuff...
  }
}

extension MyProtocol where Self: UIViewController {
  public override class func initialize()
  {
    //swizzling stuff switching viewWillAppear(_: Bool) with xxx_viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
  }

  //  MARK: - Swizzling

  func xxx_viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
  {
    self.xxx_viewWillAppear(animated)

    //invoke APIs from  
    self.protocolFunction() // MyProtocol APIs
    let viewLoaded = self.isViewLoaded // UIViewController APIs
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply =)
The problem with that is what I state in the description:

_"if we instead extend the protocol, we CAN add conditions extension MyProtocol where Self: UIViewController but **we CAN'T override methods from a class in a protocol extension**, meaning we can't public override class func initialize() which is needed for swizzling."_